# Display the results of sub category and rollup on the parent category

Tags: sql, hana

I am using SAP Hana and wanted to get the data with a roll-up to the category. Also, show the data of the subcategory.

Calculating Total

example:-
So my data currently looks like this, based on my query:

```
category    | sub_category         | count  
------------+----------------------+--------
Grocery     | Dairy                |  200  
Grocery     | fruits               |  600  
Kitchen     | Microwave            |  100  
Kitchen     | Stove                |  100  
Other       | shoes                |  400  
Other       | racks                |  500
```

What I want is:

```
category     | sub_category         | count  
-------------+----------------------+--------
Grocery      | Dairy                |  200  
Grocery      | fruits               |  600  
Total Grocery| null                 |  800
Kitchen      | Microwave            |  100  
Kitchen      | Stove                |  100  
Total Kitchen| null                 |  200 
Other        | shoes                |  400  
Other        | racks                |  500   
Total Other  | null                 |  900
```

Comment: Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one you use back.

Comment: Try Grouping Sets in your SQL. Refer to link for more details https://blogs.sap.com/2014/06/24/the-usage-of-grouping-sets-rollup-cube-in-sap-hana/